# how to detect the language of webpage content by using python

Tags: python

I have to test a bunch of URLs whether those webpages have respective translation content or not. Is there any way to return the language of content in a webpage by using the Python language?  Like if the page is in Chinese, then it should return `"Chinese"``.

I checked it with `langdetect` module, but not able to get the results I desire. These URls are in web xml format. The content is showing under `<releasehigh>`

Comment: How exactly didn't `langdetect` work for you?  What did you try and how did it fail?  Show us your code, please.

Comment: langdetect: just implement a dictionary with these values https://code.google.com/p/language-detection/wiki/LanguageList to get the language full name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract a chunk of content then use some python language detection like [langdetect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/langdetect) or [guess-language](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/guess-language).

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple example demonstrating use of [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to extract HTML body text and [langdetect](https://github.com/Mimino666/langdetect) for the language detection:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from langdetect import detect

with open("foo.html", "rb") as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, "lxml")
    [s.decompose() for s in soup("script")]  # remove <script> elements
    body_text = soup.body.get_text()
    print(detect(body_text))
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have a header like this one :

```
<HTML xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">
```

If it's the case you can see with lang="fr" that this is a french web page. If it's not the case, guessing the language of a text is not trivial.

Comment: Very frequently, the `lang` tag is inserted by automatic means, and contains a hard-coded default, rather than reflect the actual contents of the text and/or what the user would like to put there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use BeautifulSoup to extract the language from HTML source code.

```
<html class="no-js" lang="cs">
```

Extract the lang field from source code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.html["lang"])
```